# Eichler-Shimura over Totally Real Fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations

By Eichler-Shimura over totally real fields I mean the following conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Let $K$ be a totally real field. Let $f$ be a Hilbert eigenform with rational eigenvalues, of parallel weight $2$, that is new at level $\mathfrak{N}$. Then there is an elliptic curve $E_f$ over $K$ of conductor $\mathfrak{N}$ such that $$\mathrm{L}(E_f,s)=\mathrm{L}(f,s)$$.

I understand from this [paper of Zhang](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~szhang/papers/Heegner01.pdf) that the conjecture holds if $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is odd, or if $\upsilon_{\mathfrak{P}}(\mathfrak{N})=1$ for some prime $\mathfrak{P}$.

Zhang's paper appeared in 2001. What is the state of the art regarding this conjecture? What progress have been made since?

Comment: Zhang's paper that you mention has been extended in Yuan-Zhang-Zhang "Heights of CM points I: Gross-Zagier formula", http://www.math.columbia.edu/~szhang/papers/HCMI.pdf‎, perhaps they do this. I think it has been published as [this book (2013)](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9918.html).

Comment: See also this 2004 article of Don Blasius: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~blasius/papers/echmf.pdf‎ where the result is shown to follow from the Hodge conjecture.